# search cell array of character vector for header information and edit it in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

So I am trying to edit the headers of a csv file. I have imported the csv file already and removed negative numbers and replaced them with a "NAN" value. I also have been able to write out the data and headers after completing this task.

I need to search through my list of headers which come in as cell array of strings (cell array of character vectors) and fix them to fit the format of the database I am working to get these files done for. This includes:

1. making sure that after a latitude or longitude '[DEG]' exists
2. make sure that there are both north and east as well as south and west coordinates (the north south are the same and east west are the same in this case so I will just need to extract the lat or long data and concatenate it to the new header labels and insert it into the header array)
3. ensure that the date is in yyyymmdd format
4. make sure that time is in HH:MM:SS followed by [GMT] (in my example this is not true)

I have found some examples of how to search through the strings, but none of them work. I have tried strncmp, stringmatch and findstr, none of which seem to work the way I would expect. I tried:

```
strcmp(p,'\north',4)
```

p is where I pasted the below data from... the same was true when using stringmatch. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am guessing it is because I do not quite understand how to effect or use the cell data type. iscellstr=1 for my header array.

After I have the index of the cell, I am guessing, since the headers are standardized, I can relatively easily call the cell with the string I wish to edit, edit it and then return it to the cell afterward. Does it seem like I am on the right track in my thinking?

Examples headers:

```
/start_date=20110819
/end_date=20110819
/start_time=11:30[GMT]
/end_time=11:30[GMT]
/north_latitude=44.0423[DEG]
/east_longitude=-73.4302[DEG]
/south_latitude=44.0423[DEG]
/west_longitude=-73.4302[DEG]
```

Comment: Some things you should think about: Are the headers in your cell array always in the same order? Why did you put a backslash in your `strcmp` example? How did you call `stringmatch` and `findstr`, what was the result? Also, check [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the backslash was a mistake. I have decided to brute force this thing by looping through the cells converting each to a string and comparing them. While inefficient this approach works with strcmp. I may be calling the functions inappropriately, but at least strcmp is working now, although I am only comparing one string to one other at a given time.
As for the result using strcmp, it gave me [0] for all the cells. I have since moved forward and my method for adding the [GMT] and [DEG] seems to be working fine. The biggest problem I see moving forward is the date.